# How to use renderer function in extjs4 radar chart

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a radar chart with 4 radar series, i want to use renderer function for each type.

My sample code is :

series: [{ 
        type: 'radar',

```
    xField: 'name', 
    yField: 'data3', 
    renderer: function(storeItem, item, i, display){
        alert(storeItem)
    },
    showInLegend: true, 
    showMarkers : false,

    markerConfig: { 
        radius: 5, 
        size: 5            
    }, 
    style: { 
        'stroke-width': 2,
         stroke : '#FFF',
         fill: 'none' 
    } 
},{ 
    type: 'radar', 
    xField: 'name', 
    yField: 'data2', 
    showMarkers: true, 
    showInLegend: true, 
    markerConfig: { 
        radius: 5, 
        size: 5 
    }, 
    style: { 
        'stroke-width': 2,
         stroke : '#FF0',
        fill: 'none' 
    } 
},{ 
    type: 'radar', 
    xField: 'name', 
    yField: 'data5', 
    showMarkers: true, 
    showInLegend: true, 
    markerConfig: { 
        radius: 5, 
        size: 5 
    }, 
    style: { 
        'stroke-width': 2,
         stroke : '#0FF',
         fill: 'none' 
    } 
}]
```

where to add renderere function? I tried adding in all possible ways but its not working.
Am i doing any mistake? or the function is not there for radar chart?
pls some one let me know
Im using extjs4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, grep the source.

The `renderer` function is never called in a radar chart. Looks like another documentation bug. The `label.renderer` function gets called but it's only good for formatting the display text.